# How to find the current stack?

Tags: stack, metaprogramming, smalltalk, pharo

in Pharo, how can I find the currently evaluating stack?

Comment: fyi, you're not really adding value to the site if you ask a very simple question and give a very simple answer a minute later.

Comment: It was something a google query couldn't find …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in fact, the issue aint that simple: `thisContext` can be a quite expensive operation, compared to like a message send.

In Visualworks Smalltalk, stack access is *extermly* expensive because it uses the native C-stack and thus any access to `thisContext` must reify the entire C-Stack into *causally connected* Smalltalk objects. That is, for each C stack frame a Smalltalk object is to be created (including possible JIT deoptimization) and furthermore all changes to these objects must be reflected back to the C stack.

In Pharo (and Squeak, for that matter) it is less awkward, since it uses Smalltalk objects for the stack. But still the object pool which caches stack frames is flushed upon each call.  (Yes, other than eg in Java, pooling objects does improve performance in Squeak ... welcome back to the 90ies :)

Answer (score 1):

You evaluate

```
thisContext contextStack
```

Here, `thisContext` is really a special variable that points to the currently active stack frame. Then, `contextStack` returns an array with the entire stack.

Comment: what's next? How do I power my computer? You press the power button.

Comment: So it's too simple … ok, fine …